# Why does "Do you think your shit don't stink?" idiom use "don't" for uncountable noun?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Ok, [shit is an uncountable noun](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/shit_2).

But in [this idiom](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/thinks+your+shit+don't+stink), people use "**don't**" for "**shit**"

Ex: *Do you think your shit don't stink?*

Can we say "*Do you think your shit **doesn't** stink?*" or we have to say "*Do you think your shit **don't** stink?*"

Comment: If you're going to try to analyze the grammaticallity of a slang phrase, you gotta compare apples with apples. [Who says shit is uncountable?](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Two%20Shits)

Answer (score 2):

This lack of number agreement is a common feature of regional dialects; it is usually "corrected" during elementary school, where accepted standards are taught. An adult who speaks this way is typically someone who has not had much schooling or who did poorly in school, or an educated person who is deliberately using *patois*.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a vulgar slang, so the grammar doesn't matter. We actually have another version with the correct grammar and it has its place in [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/think-one-s-shit-doesn-t-stink)

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is slang, the proper phrase uses "doesn't." Using "don't" with singular nouns is just a common usage mostly among younger people. It is not grammatically correct.

To clarify, using "don't" in place of "doesn't" is very popular, at least in the US and mostly in spoken as opposed to written language. However, it is slang and shouldn't be used in formal communications.

Answer (score 1):

You can say "Do you think your shit doesn't stink?", and it is grammatically correct, but it won't have the same effect.

"Do you think your shit don't stink?" is an African American Vernacular English (AAVE, also known as Ebonics) phrase.

AAVE verb conjugation [doesn't need number agreement for present tense](http://public.wsu.edu/%7Egordonl/S2003/326/SAE_AAVE.htm).
Verb conjugation doesn't use the Standard English [third person singular](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English/Verbs) form, except for the verb ["to be"](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English/Verbs/Copula).

So, "shit doesn't stink" is correct in Standard English, but in AAVE, "shit don't stink" is correct.

Comment: Just like how we would say, "For reals." Why there's an extra "s" there on an adjective, no one knows ([Is this Spanish?!?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agreement_(linguistics)#Latin)), but hey, it works.